# Trigger Hover.css animations with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I trigger an animations from this library https://ianlunn.github.io/Hover/ with javascript?

I tried adding the class and then triggering a `mouseover` event, but that didn't work:

```
$(this).addClass('hvr-pop');
$(this).trigger('mouseover');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize you can't trigger the `:hover` class with jQuery, so I added a separate class `hvr-pop-trigger` to the .css file:

```css
.hvr-pop:hover, .hvr-pop:focus, .hvr-pop:active, .hvr-pop-trigger {
  -webkit-animation-name: hvr-pop;
  animation-name: hvr-pop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}
```

and add the class with jQuery when I want to trigger the effect:

```js
$(this).addClass('hvr-pop');
$(this).addClass('hvr-pop-trigger');
```